# Nginx location block results in requests returning a 404 status

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, devops

I am trying to automatically add a header to any response for files being fetched stored within the `/storage/` folder.

Whenever I use this location-block:

```sh
location /storage/ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}
```

I receive a 404 response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.19.4
Date: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 20:44:52 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 28300
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5fb37909-6e8c"
```

Once I comment out the location-block condition:

```sh
#location /storage/ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
#}
```

It properly adds the header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.4
Date: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 20:46:12 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 28300
Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 07:17:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5fb37909-6e8c"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Just to rule out any permission issues, I have set the file's permissions (images) I am trying to fetch as 777.

If anyone wants to browse over the complete nginx.conf, this is it:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80 default_server;
    root /;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    location /storage/ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    location /41c270e4-5535-4daa-b23e-c269744c2f45/ {
        internal;
        alias /;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ "/Users/chrisbreuer/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php" last;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log "/Users/chrisbreuer/.config/valet/Log/nginx-error.log";

    error_page 404 "/Users/chrisbreuer/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php";

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:/Users/chrisbreuer/.config/valet/valet.sock";
        fastcgi_index "/Users/chrisbreuer/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php";
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME "/Users/chrisbreuer/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php";
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Any help would be truly appreciated as I am not certain why it is throwing a 404, when it can be viewed in the browser and other headers (`Content-Type`, `Content-Length`) are properly being added, indicating that the image was "found".

Many thanks in advance!

*edit 1*

I am not sure whether it makes a difference, but the "storage" folder is a symlink.

*edit 2*

The nginx error:

```
2020/11/17 12:45:50 [error] 64990#0: *1 open() "/storage/media/1/1/turtle.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "HEAD /storage/media/1/1/turtle.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "my-api.test"
```

When I try to visit the URL in the browser `my-api.test/storage/media/1/1/turtle.jpg` it returns the image and not a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root directory for the server is set to `/`.

Therefore, when you specify /storage/ location it looks for a file in `/storage/media/1/1/turtle.jpg` - which is printed in your logs and which fails because the file is not where.

When you remove this location block, it uses `location /` which has rewrite command.

Therefore, if you modify your storage location and include proper rewrite instruction into it, this should work. Note, this will require a bit of tweaking to get this right - see documentation here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Finally, best practice for static content is to not use rewrite at all, but rather to identify proper location on disk for it and modify `root` instruction to match that location and get rid of rewrites. This should improve both performance and readability.